# как изменить атрибут элемента Playwrigh

Tags: python, playwright

как изменить `<input type="hidden">` на `<input>` . То есть как удалить этот атрибут , а вообще интересует как я могу их менять(атрибуты).

Доступ к этому элементу получаю :

```
page.frame_locator('#headlessui-tabs-panel-\:R1ktl6\: > div > div.max-w-5xl.mx-auto.py-10.sm\:px-6.lg\:max-w-full.lg\:px-8 > div > div:nth-child(2) > dl > div.flex.justify-center.items-center.mt-5 > div > div > div > div > div > iframe').locator('id=recaptcha-token')
```

могу получить его атрибут через `.get_attribute()` а как изменить не понимаю

Answer (score 0):

все еще не знаю как редактировать , удалять вот так.
(вызываю функцию на этом элементе)

```
hidden_button = page.frame_locator('#headlessui-tabs-panel-\:R1ktl6\: > div > div.max-w-5xl.mx-auto.py-10.sm\:px-6.lg\:max-w-full.lg\:px-8 > div > div:nth-child(2) > dl > div.flex.justify-center.items-center.mt-5 > div > div > div > div > div > iframe').locator('id=recaptcha-token')
hidden_button.evaluate('el => el.removeAttribute("type")')
```